# Printer describes job as "printing" while doing nothing. Tried printing document from another device and it worked perfectly

Tags: windows-10, printer, brother-printer

Good evening!
Essentially, my Brother MFC-465CN has not been able to print documents sent to it by my main computer, and I don't know why.
[Status says it's printing,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2avkD.png) but there is absolutely no change to my printer. I tried printing the exact same document from a different computer (my laptop) and it worked perfectly. Any ideas on why this might be happening? I tried turning both my PC and my printer on/off, I updated the software for the Printer and I updated my PC, I checked for newer driver versions, but there were none.

Comment: Uninstall and re-install the printer software/driver

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume there are no flashing lights or anything on the printer to indicate it is receiving data from the PC.

As the PC thinks it's printing, but the printer does not see anything, and as another PC works fine, there appears to be a problem on the main PC. You say you have "updated" the printing s/w on the PC, so I assume you have not reinstalled the printer. To do that, perform the following:

1. From Devices and Printers, delete the printer
2. Go to Control Panel > Programs & Features and delete any software relating to the printer
3. Go back to Devices & Printers, click on any other printer and select "Print server properties" from the menu that appears.
4. Click the "Drivers" tab and relate any instances of your printer (there may not be any)
5. Now reinstall.

If that does not fix it, please supply more information about how the printer is connected, and what kind of documents you are printing.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to read my post! Second of all, whenever I go into the "printers and scanners" tab, my [printer isn't listed](https://ibb.co/p2kBSyh) but when I visit the "other devices" tab, [it's there](https://ibb.co/ZWBx2GR). Is there any way you know to fix this?

Comment: That means the driver is not installed correctly. Try reinstalling as I suggested.

Comment: It tells me "The Windows 10 operating system contains the appropriate drivers, or the Windows Update system provided by Microsoft® provides the appropriate drivers for your Brother machine. These drivers are called built-in drivers." What can I do to fix this?

Comment: [This is what I see](https://ibb.co/92yVZRK)

Comment: The fact that Windows thinks the correct driver is installed does NOT verify that all driver files are correct. Similarly, updating a driver may not fix a corrupt driver, as many files are left untouched. Only a complete removal and reinstall can guarantee a correct driver.